# jQuery ajax chat reload

Tags: php, jquery, chat

I'm working on a simple webchat application for my website. However, for me, it feels wrong using interval and requesting the chat with ajax every second?

What I'm doing today is this,

```
<script>

    $(function() {

        $('#chat_form').submit(function() {
            $.post('chat/post', $('#chat_form').serialize(), function(data){
                var message = $("#message").val();
                $("#message").val('');
                $("#chat_main").append('<li><b>Bruker: <?php echo " ".$this->session->userdata("chat_username") ?></b>: ' + message + '<br/></li>');
            });
            return false;
        });

        function loadchat()
        {
            $('#chat_main').load('chat/load');
        }

        setInterval(loadchat, 500);
        loadchat();

});

</script>
```

Is there any other better way?

Comment: You don't request every time all chat posts. You need to get the posts that you don't have. e.g.: You load for first time 20 chat posts. 1st has an id of 101. You need to get all posts that are greater than "101" (I pressume that they are ordered desc.). Good luck! Also check out websocket HTML5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is](http://webscepter.com/simple-comet-implementation-using-php-and-jquery/)  really cool article regarding chat application and best way to implement comet using jQuery.

Its works for me.

There is few hack needed in order to make it perfect because its work in timestamp so when you change your machine date its fail to perform but on server its work fine.

Replace text file implementation using xml that is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

you could use [Server Side Events](http://dsheiko.com/weblog/html5-and-server-sent-events) which should allow the same thing but send the data to the browser when it has changed so the user isnt constantly requesting to see if a change has been made.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/ this is a much better link and provides a comparison between SSE and websockets plus a demo

Comment: but html5 is not fully supported i guess? so?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this couple of times. Ajax chat with polling from DB is not really a chat in real time. And you are right, using interval to poll data sucks. Anyway this is solution (one and only real solution).

[You need to read this book](http://professionalxmpp.com/). If you do not have jabber server I will give you acces to mine (user register update etc). Read the book and then contact me. It is XMPP + Strophe library chat (that what google and facebook are using)! So it is better to start over and learn something new!